# How to Update Date In FsCaldener in Swift Ios?

Tags: ios, swift, date, fscalendar

How to update date in fscalender initially while launching  an app. i am updating the date while scrolling fscalender but my doubt initially loading app how to send date to  Post service Call?

This is my api for getting dates from server.

```
let now2 = NSDate() 
let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter() 
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy" 
let nameOfyear = dateFormatter2.string(from: now2 as Date)
print("nameOfyear",nameOfyear)
let urlString = Fetch_Parent_Dashboard_Calendar_URL+"&year="+nameOfyear+"&mo‌​nth="+nameOfMonth+"&‌​branch_id=" + Userbranchid!
```

i am taking date value from user defaults sending to server when user scrolling fscalender.Following is the code for sending date to server when scrolling fscalender.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) 
{
   let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter() 
   dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" 
   let nameOfDate = dateFormatter2.string(from: date as Date)
   print("nameOfDate",nameOfDate) 
   UserDefaults.standard.set(nameOfDate, forKey: "nameOfDate")
}
```

My doubt is initially loading the app i have to send current date and scrolling time have to send that user defaults time how to handle date at this case

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: How to update date in fscalender. this is my api for getting dates from server.`let now2 = NSDate()
            let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy"
            let nameOfyear = dateFormatter2.string(from: now2 as Date)
            print("nameOfyear",nameOfyear)
            let UrlStraing = Fetch_Parent_Dashboard_Calendar_URL+"&year="+nameOfyear+"&month="+nameOfMonth+"&branch_id=" + Userbranchid!`. here i am sending current date

Comment: i am taking date value from user defaults sending to server when user scrolling fscalender.this is my code for sending date to server when scrolling fscalender.` func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
            let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            let nameOfDate = dateFormatter2.string(from: date as Date)
            print("nameOfDate",nameOfDate)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(nameOfDate, forKey: "nameOfDate")            
        }

Comment: my doubt is initially loading the app i have to send current date and scrolling time have to send that user defaults time how to handle date at this case.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you have to do like this.

Make generic function to call web service with the given date

```
func callWebServiceWithDate(date:Date)
{
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy" 
  let nameOfyear = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
  let nameOfMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  let urlString = Fetch_Parent_Dashboard_Calendar_URL+"&year="+nameOfyear+"&mo‌​nth="+nameOfMonth+"&‌​branch_id=" + Userbranchid!
}
```

Now call this method from `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method with `Date()` as input parameter for initial call.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.callWebServiceWithDate(date: Date())
}
```

And call the same method from FSCalendars delegate method

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) 
{
   self.callWebServiceWithDate(date: date)
}
```

Comment: Hi raki thank you for quick solution let me try this solution .

Comment: but i am calling Service function in another class and using that function with shared instance . so how can i Make generic function to call web service with the given date.

Comment: write the function in that class (Just copy from here and paste it there)